# Error while trying to invoke function via web3

Tags: solidity

I read all the documentation, but this simple example that tries to invoke function doesn't work.

The initiation:

> var contractAbi = web3.eth.contract(myABI);
>
> var myContract = contractAbi.at(myAddress);

seems to be okay. But:

> myContract.methods.dummy().call({from: web3.eth.accounts[0],data:getData}, function(error, result){
>     if(!error)
>     {
>         console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
>         console.log(result);
>       }
>     else
>         console.error(error);
>   });

raise the following exception:

> myContract.methods is undefined

while the following code:

> var getData = myContract.dummy.getData()
>   web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:myAddress, from:web3.eth.accounts[0],data:getData, gas:30000 },function(error, result){
>       if(!error)
>       {
>           console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
>           console.log(result);
>         }
>       else
>           console.error(error);
>   });

Pops a metamask transaction creation pop-up, and the return value is not my function "dummy" value.

Thanks for the help.

More information:

I includes :

> < script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js">

and also the following standart code:

> window.addEventListener('load', function() {
>     // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
>     if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
>       // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
>       web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
>       startApp()
>     } else {
>        console.error("Please use a web3 browser");
>       // Handle the case where the user doesn't have Metamask installed
>       // Probably show them a message prompting them to install Metamask
>     }
>     // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
>   })

Comment: Which version of web3js are you using?

Comment: This one: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/dist/web3.min.js

Answer (score 1):

With version 1.0 of web3, contract is now Contract (note the capital C).

Change this:

```
web3.eth.contract(myABI);
```

to this:

```
web3.eth.Contract(myABI);
```